# Is there a way to "grow" my array as my program continues?

Tags: c++, types, primes

I am creating a prime generator in c++ using an array to store primes as I find them and then use them to check against potentials later. Is there a way to "grow" my array as my program continues?

Comment: If **YOU** are thinking of voting to close this question as "not real" and "impossible to answer" just because you can't think of any answer, note that it has already been answered. I.e. that it is *not* impossible to answer. If you are one of those at least 3 who has already voted that way, what's *wrong* with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a std:vector something like this:

```
vector<int> primes;
```

then you would add primes to it by using:

```
primes.push_back(2);
```

and retrieve values from the vector by using:

```
primes[0];
```

Good luck!

Comment: @BrettHale: `std::vector` doesn't reallocate for every `push_back`. The standard guarantees _amortized constant time_ growth.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, my mistake - that's true for at-end insert/delete.

Comment: @Fib Wall: I would also recommend testing with `std::deque`.  It's slightly slower to use `[]`, but slightly faster for the reallocation.  Test, and see which of them is faster.

Answer (score 6):

See std:vector.
http://new.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::vector` template, and use the `reserve` method based on an upper-bound for the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is probably a std::list; whereas a vector needs to reallocate previously stored items when its reserved space is exceeded, this doesn't happen with a list.

Comment: The OP wants to use the array to check against potentials later. This would probably involve a binary search. Lists and binary searches don't mix very well.

Answer (score 0):

The usual cases where this sort of need arises also require an efficient lookup operation. My experience is to go for `std::map` which makes life much easier than vectors here.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any initially known limit to which you are going to go, you can just calculate the length of the array you need with this simple formula:

let `N` is that limit and `LENGTH` is the needed length of the array, so

`LENGTH = N / log(N)`

where the `log(N)` is a natural logarithm of `N`

for more information, see: [Prime number distribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).